# Can't build aws-mwaa-local-runner image on Docker for Windows, possible issue with Flask-OpenID

Tags: python, flask, openid, setuptools

I'm having problem building Docker image from aws-mwaa-local-runner repository (using their release [v2.0.2](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/releases/tag/v2.0.2)). Apparently it has problem with Flask-OpenID 1.2.5 (see output below) but I'm lost as to how to resolve it.

For the record, I tried this with Docker for Windows version 20.10.12, Ubuntu distro running with Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2, Kernel version 5.10.16.

```
=> [ 7/13] RUN chmod u+x /bootstrap.sh && /bootstrap.sh

...

#11 67.25 Collecting Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5
#11 67.30   Downloading Flask-OpenID-1.2.5.tar.gz (43 kB)
#11 67.32      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 43.4/43.4 KB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#11 67.33   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#11 67.51   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#11 67.52   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#11 67.52
#11 67.52   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#11 67.52   │ exit code: 1
#11 67.52   ╰─> [1 lines of output]
#11 67.52       error in Flask-OpenID setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
#11 67.52       [end of output]
#11 67.52
#11 67.52   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#11 67.52 error: metadata-generation-failed
#11 67.52
#11 67.52 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#11 67.52 ╰─> See above for output.
#11 67.52
#11 67.52 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#11 67.52 hint: See above for details.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chmod u+x /bootstrap.sh && /bootstrap.sh]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I was able to solve this issue by changing Flask-OpenID version in `/docker/config/requirements.txt` and `/docker/config/constraints.txt` from 1.2.5 to [1.3.0](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-openid/releases/tag/v1.3.0) and finished building the image successfully.